# Login and mantaign session from ios app to a symfony2 web application

Tags: ios, session, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have developed a Web Application using Symfony2. I have used **FOSUserBundle** for user management and security.

Now I am thinking of developing a native iOS APP for my web and don't really know how to approach the issue of creating a session from the APP and mantaign it throughout the interaction user-APP.

In other words, I want to make sure that when I do a `NSURLRequest`, somehow the session token is sent to allow the server relate all of the requests in the same session.

Is there anything special to do when creating the session in the PHP side?
Is there anything special to do when handling requests from an iOS APP?

Could you mention some good articles to learn on how to get this approach?. I want to do it well from the beggining.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to rely on a stateless authentication.

On the server side, have a look at the [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) that implements the server side of OAuth2 . The process would be to request the api an access_token from the user credentials, and then pass the access_token on each request.

On the iOS side, I recommend using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to make HTTP requests, with [AFOAuth2Client](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client) to request an access_token.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Ugh :S... a little too much for a starting newbie in security like me. Apart from each framework documentation, could you explain the whole thing or redirect me to any place where this workflow is explained? I need to put each thing in its place to get to understand each piece and the whole thing. Thanks again :)

Comment: You can read this tutorial about OAuth2 : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/index.html

Comment: Thanks.Seeing the introduction and a little in the workflow, I think that that is not what I was looking for. I have a database against which I am validating the users in a very classic Client/Server web authentication (using FOSUserBundle).It's me who is authenticating the users. Now, what I want is to create an iOS APP that will have to authenticate against that same DB using an API I can create with actual Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle. What you did send me is not more for using Facebook or Twitter to authenticate the users in my site? Thanks again. I hope you don't get tired of my questions.

Comment: Basically, with FOSOAuthServerBundle, you can authenticate against the api, that will return a token on success. Then you'll have to send the token with each request.
Eg:
1. Request token (GET /oauth/v2/token?...username=email&password=pwd ... returns ABC)
2. Request any other url authenticated GET /potatoes?access_token=ABC

Comment: Great! I got it now. I am definitely trying this approach. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello again. According to your last comment and to the tutorial, that would be to use the third method of Authorization Grant (Resource Owner Password Credentials)... is that correct? But, in this case, is it not necessary to previously send a client_id in the request. Is it correct to say that it is not client dependent that third method? Thank you again.

Comment: @ElPiter For the grant type, that's it. But you still need a client (that just represents the ios/android/web app etc...)

Comment: Thanks again. But let me go a little further. I still haven't started this part of the development. Just reading for now. But I am missing something important and I'll ask you as I see you are sort of an expert: according to FOSOAuthServerBundle documentation, the client Entity just have a clientID. Isn't it supposed to save the secret aswell in order for it to authenticate properly? And one more related question: does it offer any kind of command or anything to add new clients? I am missing all that part. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: No command is provided, because it's fast to implement, or you could use SonataAdmin to manage this.

Comment: Because the client class you create inherit from a BaseClient from the client, it also inherits the already defined properties ... see https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Model/Client.php and https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/doctrine/Client.orm.xml

Comment: Thank you! Yep... That was such an obvious thing that I didn't realise. I mounted it all yesterday night and I keep going this evening. Something I am still missing is a command or some administration tool to add clients, tokens, etc... I can't thing of doing it all manually, as they seem to need to be generated with some kind of secure algorithm, etc, etc... Any additional instruction on that? Thanks again

Comment: You could setup SonataAdminBundle to easily manage clients. You can find a project i did that uses FOSOAuthServerBundle and SonataAdminBundle to manage clients there: https://github.com/adrienbrault/SUPINFO-B3-YouFood-Server/tree/master/src/YouFood/ApiBundle/Admin

Comment: Uhm... interesting... I definitely have a look on SonataAdminBundle. Thank you

Comment: Hello again. I hope you are still there :(. Step by step I am getting to go forward. But now I am stuck here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545719/oauth2-how-to-link-access-token-with-an-actual-user. Would be great if you took a look. Basically, I get the user to enter his/her credentials, I validate the session, I get the access_token, and all seems to go fine. But when, once I get all that, I go and try to get an items lists of the user that has entered his credentials, I don't get the session to remain in the server side, and I get typical non session errors. What step am I missing?

Comment: By the way, I have used GTM-oauth2 Google libraries in the iOS client side. I hope that is not the problem. It uses Bearer method.

Comment: Hey @AdrienBrault, your answer is really good, many thanks for this. I just have a quick question, wouldn't it be better to use the Password Flow Grant Type (in the [document](http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/18/oauth2-explained-part-3-using-oauth2-with-your-bare-hands) you mentioned) instead of the Authorization Code Grant Type? I mean from an iOS app like in this case, would you still recommend Authorization Code Grant Type? I am just looking into this, but I don't know if the redirection would be useful in that particular case. Any chance I could have your thoughts on this? Cheers!

Comment: @Patt If the oauth client is trusted, you can use the password flow without problem.