# Oauth2 - how to link access_token with an actual user

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Using symfony2, fosuserbundle, fosoauthserverbundle and gtm-oauth2, once you have gotten the authorization token, how the oauth engine links (or relates) it with the user that entered his login/password credentials?

I am not talking about some google or Facebook or twitter or Instagram API, but one I am supposed to be serving in a site I have created I pup with symfony2.0.

I am getting perfectly the access token and I have it for whatever I have to do with it.

So here comes the question. What do I have to do with it both in client and server sides to make the whole thing relate the token with the user. In other words, once I have the token in the iOS app, I need to access to a URL that will response a json string with certain items belonging to the user. But at the moment I just get the HTML of the authentication form as it is interpretting that the user isn't loged in yet.

I edit to specify the differences between using the ios app and the browser. Really diferent, but I don't have a clue about how to act or what to do.

Debug when calling from iOS APP:

```
[2012-09-23 01:30:43] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:43] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\RouterListener::onEarlyKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:43] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:43] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:43] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:43] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:43] request.INFO: Matched route "_get_carts_api" (parameters: "_controller": "Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\APIController::getCartsApiAction", "_route": "_get_carts_api") [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:43] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:44] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:44] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:44] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:44] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:44] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Controller\ControllerListener::onCoreController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:30:44] app.INFO: anon. [] [
```

Debug when using the web from the browser:

```
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\RouterListener::onEarlyKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] doctrine.DEBUG: SET NAMES UTF8 ([]) [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17, t0.name AS name18, t0.address AS address19, t0.nif AS nif20, t0.phone AS phone21, t0.account_number AS account_number22, t0.zip AS zip23, t0.town AS town24, t0.province AS province25, t0.birth_date AS birth_date26, t0.myTestsHelpActive AS myTestsHelpActive27, t0.myPackagesHelpActive AS myPackagesHelpActive28, t0.historyHelpActive AS historyHelpActive29, t0.shopHelpActive AS shopHelpActive30, t0.sellerPackageHelpActive AS sellerPackageHelpActive31, t0.testHours AS testHours32, t0.testMinutes AS testMinutes33, t0.wrongSubstract AS wrongSubstract34, t0.archivedPackages AS archivedPackages35 FROM usuario t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ? (["pgbonino@gmail.com"]) [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] security.DEBUG: Username "pgbonino@gmail.com" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] request.INFO: Matched route "_get_carts" (parameters: "_controller": "Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\ShopController::getCartsAction", "_route": "_get_carts") [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Controller\ControllerListener::onCoreController". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.create_date AS create_date3, t0.update_date AS update_date4, t0.user_id AS user_id5 FROM Cart t0 WHERE t0.user_id = ? ([100]) [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.description AS description3, t0.prize AS prize4, t0.update_time AS update_time5, t0.update_comment AS update_comment6, t0.active AS active7, t0.user_id AS user_id8, t0.block_id AS block_id9 FROM package t0 INNER JOIN packages_carts ON t0.id = packages_carts.package_id WHERE packages_carts.cart_id = ? ([11]) [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2012-09-23 01:28:07] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []]
```

Edited: this is what both Authorize and Token Requests are writing in debug logs:

```
[2012-09-23 13:53:12] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_oauth_server_authorize" (parameters: "_controller": "FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\AuthorizeController::authorizeAction", "_route": "fos_oauth_server_authorize"). Request: GET /~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/auth?client_id=1_2854cesqrsu8oosk8k40sw0ck4kccgooowc4s80gk4gssc4g00&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2F~pgbonino%2FSymfony%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Foauth%2Fv2%2FfalseCallBack&response_type=code HTTP/1.1
Accept:          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection:      keep-alive
Cookie:          PHPSESSID=o6fmhfinrfv7ueht3hmgt91jf6
Host:            127.0.0.1
Origin:          http://127.0.0.1
Referer:         http://127.0.0.1/~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/main/
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10A403
X-Php-Ob-Level:  1

[2012-09-23 13:53:13] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_oauth_server_token" (parameters: "_controller": "fos_oauth_server.controller.token:tokenAction", "_route": "fos_oauth_server_token"). Request: POST /~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token HTTP/1.1
Accept:          */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  312
Content-Type:    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:            127.0.0.1
User-Agent:      gtm-oauth2 Gallello.PruebasAPI/1.0
X-Php-Ob-Level:  1

client_id=1_2854cesqrsu8oosk8k40sw0ck4kccgooowc4s80gk4gssc4g00&client_secret=sr93lkss5hc48kg0csw4ksk0goccsc4g00448gc8s0k4s4csk&code=UnNDaUkdl6YAkr53uwctnuZLpota6X-jSBq4gqB1XfE&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2F~pgbonino%2FSymfony%2Fweb%2Fapp_dev.php%2Foauth%2Fv2%2FfalseCallBack

[2012-09-23 14:02:47] request.INFO: Matched route "_get_carts_api" (parameters: "_controller": "Acme\StoreBundle\Controller\APIController::getCartsApiAction", "_route": "_get_carts_api"). Request: GET /~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/api/getCarts HTTP/1.1
Accept:          */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection:      keep-alive
Cookie:          PHPSESSID=6apagmbmr4b7dddf3r44ecgp30
Host:            127.0.0.1
User-Agent:      PruebasAPI/1.0 CFNetwork/609 Darwin/12.2.0
X-Php-Ob-Level:  1
```

And next, the XCode where I have it all done:

First, first, declare and prepare the object that the request will be performed with:

```
- (GTMOAuth2Authentication * ) authForPreparaTest
{
//This URL is defined by the individual 3rd party APIs, be sure to read their documentation
NSString * url_string = @"http://127.0.0.1/~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token";
NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];
// We'll make up an arbitrary redirectURI.  The controller will watch for
// the server to redirect the web view to this URI, but this URI will not be
// loaded, so it need not be for any actual web page.
NSString * redirectURI = @"http://127.0.0.1/~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/falseCallBack";
GTMOAuth2Authentication * myAuth;
myAuth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"PreparaTest"
                                                         tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                      redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                         clientID:kMyClientID
                                                     clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
        ];
[myAuth setTokenType:@"Bearer"];
return myAuth;
}
```

Second, push the webview with my web application asking the user for their credentials:

```
- (void)signInToPreparaTest
{
GTMOAuth2Authentication *myAuth = [self authForPreparaTest];
NSString* auth_string = @"http://127.0.0.1/~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/auth";
NSURL * authURL = [NSURL URLWithString:auth_string];
// Display the authentication view


GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController;
viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:myAuth
                                                             authorizationURL:authURL
                                                             keychainItemName:nil
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                             finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
[viewController setBrowserCookiesURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1/~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/"]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Third, all goes perfectly, so update the self.auth object with the access_token:

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)myAuth
             error:(NSError *)error
{
if (error != nil)
{
    // Authentication failed
    UIAlertView *alertView = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Failed"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
else
{
    // Authentication succeeded

    // Assign the access token to the instance property for later use
    self.accessToken = myAuth.accessToken;
    [myAuth setShouldAuthorizeAllRequests:YES];
    [self setAuth:myAuth];

    // Display the access token to the user
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Succeeded"
                                                         message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Access Token: %@", auth.accessToken]
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Forth and last (the problematic moment), once authenticated, I go for my API (I want all saved carts for the logged user):

```
- (IBAction)getCartsPressed:(id)sender{

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];

NSString * url_string = @"http://127.0.0.1/~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/api/getCarts";
NSURL *getCartsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];

[request setURL:getCartsURL];

[self.auth authorizeRequest:request
          completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
              NSString *output = nil;
              if (error) {
                  output = [error description];
              } else {
                  // Synchronous fetches like this are a really bad idea in Cocoa applications
                  //
                  // For a very easy async alternative, we could use GTMHTTPFetcher
                  NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                  NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                       returningResponse:&response
                                                                   error:&error];
                  if (data) {
                      // API fetch succeeded
                      output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                  } else {
                      // fetch failed
                      output = [error description];
                  }
              }
          }];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `$container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();` returns a user ?

Comment: Nop, it doesn't. The problem is right there, but only when calling the controller of the API. The rest of the Web application works well from a browser, creating the session with the user credentials in a "traditional way" and the line of code that you mention brings correctly the user data. From the iOS APP I aparently create the session, get the access token (I check it in the database and does it perfectly), but when I call again as said in GTM-oauth2 documentation,  $container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser() returns Uninitialized value. :'(

Comment: I edited to paste the traces when calling from iOS APP and from web browser. I hope you can take a look

Comment: Do you think it could have anything to do with the way GTM-oauth2 is requesting the URL? I guess FOSOAuthServerBundle is not expecting the token as it is sent here -->       // we have a likely valid access token
      NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s %@",
                         GTM_OAUTH2_BEARER, accessToken];
      [request setValue:value forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    }

Comment: `security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token` Here's the issue. What endpoint with what params do you use to get an access token ?

Comment: Thank you again. I just wrote at the end of the original post what both Authorize and Token requests write in the debug logs. As I said before, note that it is all generated by GTM-oauth2. There you have also the logs for the request I am trying to perform after I get the token (I mean... when I call to the API)

Comment: And now I posted at the end of the original question the Objective-C code that is trying (and almost getting) all of it. I know it is long... but it all makes sense. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Another clue: I think the problem is not on how I am getting the access_token (which, as I said, I am getting properly and I get it saved in the DB), but on the latest request, where I am trying to call my API to get all the saved carts of the previously (and supposedly) authenticated user. If you see that part of the trace, you'll check how the */api/getCarts request is being made without parameters. Don't  you think GTM-oauth2 is missing to send somehow the token? I can try to do it manually, what is the exact name of the parameters expected in FOSOAuthServerBundle where the token has to go?

Comment: Uhm... apparently it worked!! Let me check a little more, but it seems that setting manually the token in the http header it worked. I'll check it a little more and I'll post the answer if it is really the solution. Thanks again.