# iOS authentication with Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle

Tags: iphone, ios, symfony, afnetworking, fosuserbundle

I have developped a **`Symfony2`** website which is using **`FOSUserBundle`**.

I am developping an **iOS app** which is linked to my website through **`AFNetworking`** requests and JSON responses.

I am just missing the user authentication so that when a user opens the app he has to login (if not remembered) and then on each `AFNetworking` request I can pass the user info (an id, a token, a username/password, ...) so that the response is secured and personalized.

I have spent the past days looking for the right solution and I have seen so many different (complicated) ways of doing it. But from what I understand I only miss 2 steps:

1. Send a request from iOS app to Symfony2 with username/password and return true if the user matches
2. Add the username/password (stored with `SSKeychain` as I understood) to every `AFNetworking` request.

Is it correct ? And how would I implement the following then:

- Test in the `Symfony2` controller if username/password is correct and return true or an `authToken` in JSON
- Make that `AFNetworking` requests are accessible under the security firewall with given username/password or auth token in parameters and find the user in database to send him back his own data.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the FOSOAuthServerBundle

Comment: Thank you I am working on it and it seems to be the perfect fit for my needs.

Comment: @JulesMarcilhacy did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOSAuthServerBundle was indeed the perfect bundle to add authentication to a Symfony2 project from an iOS app.

A good tutorial to implement it can be found here:

http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/16/oauth2-explained-part-1-principles-and-terminology/

Comment: [This answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347319/login-and-mantaign-session-from-ios-app-to-a-symfony2-web-application#answer-12351948) could be of interest to people.